# Populate textbox with related data from dropdownlist selected index

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a working cascading dropdown list, whereby, once I select one value, it populates the second dropdown by use of JSON. I don't know how to pass this second dropdownlist index (and also whenever it is changed) to my controller to display corresponding data from my model.

My json dropdownlist is as follows

```
$(function () { 
    $('#VoyageDivID').hide(); 
    $('#tabsDiv').hide();

    $('#Vessel_ID').change(function () { 
        var URL = $('#VesselVoyageFormID').data('voyagelistaction')+'/' + $('#Vessel_ID').val(); 

        $.getJSON(URL, function (data) { 
            var items = ""; 
            $.each(data, function (i, voyage) { 
                items += "<option value='" + voyage.Value + "'>" + voyage.Text + "</option>"; 
            }); 

            $('#Voyage_ID').html(items); 
            $('#VoyageDivID').show(); 
            $('#tabsDiv').show();

        }); 
    }); 

    $('#Voyage_ID').change(function () { 
        $('#tabsDiv').show();
        //need to show the related data here whenever the dropdownlist is changed
    }); 
});
```

VIEW

```
<div id="tabsDiv">

<div class="editor-label">
      XYZ
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.XYZ)
    </div>        
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult VoyageList(int ID)
{
    // int voyageID = ID;
    var voyages = from s in db.EXAMPLE.OrderByDescending(i => i.Voyage_ID).ToList()
                  where s.Vessel_ID == ID
                  select s;

    if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())//only if it comes from list
        return Json(new SelectList(
                        voyages.ToArray(),
                        "Voyage_ID",
                        "Voyage_ID")
                   , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```